# How to zoom entities/datasources with Cesium?

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

I tried:

```
czmlDataSource.load(czmlurl).then(function(){
                                viewer.dataSources.add(czmlDataSource).then(function(){
                                    viewer.flyTo(viewer.dataSources,offset);
                                });
                          });
```

This:

```
czmlDataSource.load(czmlurl).then(function(){
                                viewer.dataSources.add(czmlDataSource).then(function(){
                                    viewer.zoomTo(viewer.dataSources,offset);
                                });
                          });
```

And this:

```
czmlDataSource.load(czmlurl).then(function(){
                                viewer.dataSources.add(czmlDataSource);
                                viewer.flyTo(viewer.dataSources,offset);
                          });
```

And its `.zoomTo` equivalent without success. What to do now?

Edit: The answer that works is: viewer.flyTo(czmlDataSource) I thought I had to use the viewer's data source as in viewer.DataSources, which was my mistake, that did not work.

Stack overflow has become so stale people waste their time correcting grammar and spelling on 3 year old posts.

Comment: Please provide full code context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
viewer.dataSources.add(czmlDataSource);
czmlDataSource.load(czmlurl).then(function() {
    viewer.flyTo(czmlDataSource, options);
});
```

See also: [viewer.flyTo](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/Viewer.html#flyTo) for the available `options`.

Also remember to check the web console for any errors, and include them with your question if they are relevant.

Comment: This did not give me any errors, that's why I posted the question, anyhow your answer is the right one, thanks!